# When border top and bottom got higher value from left and right, they seems shorter?

Tags: html, css, border

It seems short borders when i use lower values on both sides of an element, [**here is jsFiddle to inspect.**](http://jsfiddle.net/8Rhf7/6/) How can i straighten side borders when they have different values? Hope can find a fix.

```
span {
    float: left;
    border-top: 10px solid red;
    border-bottom: 10px solid red;
    border-right: 1px solid blue;
    border-left: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 0 10px 0 20px;
    background: orange;
}
```

[image: Short border value example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will always behave like that. As you can see on your own example, the borders are divided by diagonal lines. You could achieve your behaviour by wrapping two spans into each other. One for the vertical borders, the other one for the horizontal.

[Fiddle-Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8Rhf7/7/)

```
<span class="vertical">
    <span class="horizontal">
    Problem Here, left and right border is shorter
    </span>
</span>
```

btw: I'd recommend `box-sizing: border-box` for a more intuitive behaviour of widths and heights for elements (compare padding behaviour):

[Fiddle-Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8Rhf7/11/)